# Why Chrome Refreshes the URL after certain minutes of receiving no response?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express

In my node application I have an anchor tag which when clicked will request an Express `GET` route which makes some API calls and render the response in an EJS template.

When the API being requested from Express route takes too long to respond, the Node express route URL gets requested again **automatically**.
Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

In [HTTP/1.1 Connections](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4):

> 8.2.4 Client Behavior if Server Prematurely Closes Connection: 
>   If an HTTP/1.1 client sends a request which includes a request body,
>   but which does not include an Expect request-header field with the
>   "100-continue" expectation, and if the client is not directly
>   connected to an HTTP/1.1 origin server, and if the client sees the
>   connection close before receiving any status from the server, the
>   client SHOULD retry the request

Browsers mostly will re-try a connecton until a proper response is given, on Chrome i believe it's 5 attempts.

It's a expected behavior.
There's a nice [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries) from Oracle's blog that has a similar scenario described.

Comment: Note that most browsers only retry get routes multiple times, they usually don't do this for post